# Angular 6: get array of objects from corresponding JSON through httpClient

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to populate a table with data from my backend API. The table expects a `rows` input that's an array of objects, with each object representing a row in the table and consisting of column-name/value pairs. The backend posts an array of JSON objects like this:

`[{"column1":"val1","column2":"val2"},{"column1":"valA","column2":"valB"}]`

If I just copy and paste that string into my .ts file and assign it directly to the rows property, everything works correctly:

```
this.rows = [{"column1":"val1","column2":"val2"},{"column1":"valA","column2":"valB"}]
```

This works regardless of whether the `rows` property is defined as `any` or `Array<DataObject>` or anything in between. So why can't I seem to achieve the same functionality through httpClient?

Here's what I have so far:

data-service.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

    public getData() {
        return this.http.get<Array<DataObject>>(apiURL, {responseType : 'json'});
    }
```

table-view.route.ts:

```
export class TableView implements OnInit {

    rows: Array<DataObject>;

    constructor(dataService: DataService) {
        dataService.getData()
                   .subscribe((result: Array<DataObject>) => this.rows = result)
    }
}
```

data-object.ts

```
export interface DataObject {
    column1: string;
    column2: string;
}
```

This seems to be correctly fetching the data, but it's typed wrong or wrapped in an extra object or something and the table can't read it. No errors; just empty table. Interestingly, I added this to my html before the table declaration just to make sure my data was getting through:

```
<div>{{rows[0].column1}}</div>
```

This correctly outputs "val1", AND it suddenly populates the table with ALL the data. Does this access somehow change the type of `rows` into something the table component can understand?

I've tried all sorts of variations of the above code with and without type-checking; I've tried removing the json content header, reading it as plaintext, then using `JSON.parse()`. I realize that I could just iterate through the array, instantiating `DataObject`s and mapping the fields individually before pushing them to `rows`, but there has to be a simpler way to do this, right...? Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: try `rows: Array<DataObject>=[]`

Comment: Can you show the JSON that is coming back from the server? You should be able to find it in the network section of your browsers dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because `this.rows = result` is not wrapped in `{}`. Can you log out your subscription to make sure it's actually coming back?

```
dataService.getData()
.subscribe(
  (result: Array<DataObject>) => { 
    console.log('success', result);
    this.rows = result
  },
  (error: any) => { 
    console.log('error', error);
  }
)
```

I would also suggest moving that call to NgOnInit rather than the constructor.

Comment: Good call on the logging; turns out the Table View route is correctly decoding the objects from the subscription after all. The problem is that the Table component itself gets initialized before that happens, so the `rows` input is empty. Using the table's search/sort features seems to recheck the input and then everything appears correctly. I'm gonna play around with it. This response timing stuff seems pretty fundamental. Any suggestions for articles/tutorials to brush up on it?

Comment: Note: I just wrapped the table component in a `div` with `*ngIf="rows"` and that solved it completely.